# Enter Button Issue -- Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

I want to link an Enter Button (on a keyboard) to text box in javascript and the problem is there are two submit buttons linked to it. I researched a bit and realized that i can use keypress like this

```
$('#searchbox input').bind('keypress', function(e) {});
```

If there is one submit button.

Does any one have idea on how to make it work for my code?

html:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post"> 
    id: <input type="text" name="id" id="id"/>
    <div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
        age: <input type="text" name="age"/>
        <input type="button" id="button2" value="Update" />
    </div> 
    <input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = ''; this.style.display = 'none'" size="25"/>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){ 
        $.post('fet.php', { id: $('input[name="id"]', '#myForm').val() },
            function(json) { 
                $("input[name='age']").val(json.age);
            }, "json");  
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $('form#myForm').attr({action: "fetch2.php"});
        $('form#myForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like there is something wrong with your syntax. Did you copy correctly?

Comment: @primvbd if it is some thing to do with closing or opening brackets in jquery plzz ignore

Comment: after trying to edit your post I realize your syntax is totally bunked or you copied and pasted it wrong. Is this everything?

Comment: I don't see any submit buttons in your markup

Comment: @hunter input type = "button"

Comment: `input type="button"` is not the same as `input type="submit"`. Not trying to be picky, but this is an important fact since a `submit` will submit a form and having one can trigger the submit on enter.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('#searchbox input:text').keypress(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();//avoid submitting the form
   if(e.which == 13){
      //Enter pressed

   }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#searchbox input:text').bind('keypress', function(e) {

   if(e.which == 13){//Enter pressed
      //Do your stuff here
   }    
});
```